# How to stop notifications and UI changes from the host computer to show in the remoted computer?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I RDP from computer A into computer B, I am seeing some UI updates that happen in computer A showing while I am in computer B. For example, I have a scheduled job in computer A which launches a console app every hour. The console UI shows up while I am on computer B.  Also, I see some notifications from computer A's tasktray apps showing up in computer B. I am using full-screen mode while remoting.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Unclear: RDP will show the remote taskbar and its notifications. Do you want to disable notifications on the remote computer while doing RDP?

Comment: What are you calling a 'remote' computer? Please use computer A and computer B notation liked I mentioned so everything is clear. Computer B, computer being remoted into) is showing notifications and command window that belong to the computer that initiated the rdp session. I don't want computer B showing stuff that belong to computer A.

Comment: Do you mean that while remoting into B at full-screen you don't want to see local notifications from your own computer A? I don't think that they are coming up in B - they are showing in A, just being displayed on top of the RDP local window that is showing B.

Comment: Yes, that's what I specifically said in my question. I don't want the command window from computer A showing up in computer B when the app launches there.

Comment: You're losing me there : What exactly happens with the command window?

Comment: It shows up when the app runs and then the window disappears. That's expected on computer A. It's not expected when I am in computer B. Same for tasktray notifications. I shouldn't be seeing anything from computer A. It seems RDP is relaying these to be shown on the other computer.

Comment: Seems like you wish the RDP to be the topmost window, so it won't be occulted. That can be arranged, if you want.

Comment: How can it be arranged?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to set the RDP window as topmost, so other programs or
notification do not position themselves on top of it.

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
to set the active window as the topmost:

```
^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)